# Launcher.LaunchUriAsync in winrt xaml app

Tags: c#, .net, windows, xaml, winrt-xaml

I use Launcher.LaunchUriAsync to connect to a website from my winrt xaml app.However ,the website is private and it asks me for authorisation credentials every time I try to connect.Any idea on how the credentials can be encrypted and passed along with uri in LaunchUriAsync?

Comment: The url format doesn't work in IE anymore.Anyways,I cannot achieve the functionality in launchURIAync directly.I achieved this by using a external windows form with the Winrt xaml app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to pass any parameter in `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync`  method except the url, so if you could find a way to pass the credentials with the url if the website you trying to reach will accept it..

I've searched and I found this:
you could use this url format: `http://username:password@example.com`

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

Again, it depends on the website and the authentication method.

Comment: The url format doesn't work in IE anymore.Anyways,I cannot achieve the functionality in launchURIAync directly.I achieved this by using a external windows form with the Winrt xaml app.